# Software installation problem: cannot adding path to /usr/local/bin

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation

I am currently installing a software in a local directory(/some/local/directory/bin/). I tried to copy it into the usr/local/bin/ but I am not allowed. I am wondering that how can I execute the software? Is it possible to not have its path added to the usr/local/bin?

(I'm trying to install samtools. So if i can successfully install it into local/bin, I should call "samtools command file" to let it execute. But now that I can only install it into a local directory/bin, what should I call in order to execute it?)

Comment: If you want to create a link in `/usr/local/bin`, use `sudo ln -s ...`  (ie. elevate your privileges using `sudo` to write into that directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options.

You can either add the folder with the binary to the `PATH` environment variable or add a symbolic link to the binary file into one of the directories which appear in `PATH` (`/usr/local/bin`) for example.